# Getting Mac movie info from command line

Tags: macos, tv, metadata

Is there any way to get movie info from movies in the TV (née iTunes) app on the Mac? I’m not talking about tech info from ‘mdls’; I’m talking about the info in the Info box from the app: i.e, director, cast, crew, etc. The information has to be on the system somewhere, so how do I get to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get that using AppleScript, which has the benefit of talking directly to iTunes, but it's not as easy to use in that manner from the command-line.

If you want command-line access, I highly recommended [MP4Tools](https://www.mp4joiner.org/en/).  I think you need to compile it yourself, unless there is a "port" (MacPorts) or Homebrew for it.  You can also use ffprobe, part of the ffmpeg suite, which you can definitely get thru MacPorts and/or Homebrew, I forget which I'm using.

UPDATE:

**Output from ffprobe:**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Lawrence of Arabia.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2012-06-12T12:41:36.000000Z
    title           : Lawrence of Arabia 
    artist          : Peter O'Toole
    genre           : Action & Adventure
    date            : 1962
    compilation     : 0
    sort_artist     : O'Toole, Peter
    description     : This monumental story recounts the true-life experiences of T.E Lawrence, better known to the world as Lawrence of Arabia. 
    synopsis        : One of the screen's grandest epics, this monumental story recounts the true-life experiences of T.E. Lawrence, better known to the world as Lawrence of Arabia. A young, idealistic British officer in WWI, Lawrence (Peter O'Toole) is assigned to the camp of
    copyright       : © 1962 renewed 1990 Columbia Pictures Industries, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    purchase_date   : 2014-05-06 13:48:29
    podcast         : 0
    hd_video        : 1
    media_type      : 9
    rating          : 0
    gapless_playback: 0
    account_id      : (redacted)
    account_type    : 0
    iTunMOVI        : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    : <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
                    : <plist version="1.0">
                    : <dict>
                    :   <key>cast</key>
                    :   <array>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Peter O'Toole</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Alec Guinness</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Anthony Quinn</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Jack Hawkins</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Omar Sharif</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Jose Ferrer</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Anthony Quayle</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Claude Rains</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Arthur Kennedy</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :   </array>
                    :   <key>codirectors</key>
                    :   <array/>
                    :   <key>directors</key>
                    :   <array>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>David Lean</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :   </array>
                    :   <key>producers</key>
                    :   <array>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Sam Spiegel</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :   </array>
                    :   <key>screenwriters</key>
                    :   <array>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Robert Bolt</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :       <dict>
                    :           <key>name</key>
                    :           <string>Michael Wilson</string>
                    :       </dict>
                    :   </array>
                    :   <key>studio</key>
                    :   <string>Horizon Pictures</string>
                    : </dict>
                    : </plist>
                    : 
    iTunEXTC        : mpaa|PG|200|
  Duration: 03:42:11.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4643 kb/s
...
```

**Output from mp4info:**

```
 Name: Lawrence of Arabia 
 Artist: Peter O'Toole
 Sort Artist: O'Toole, Peter
 Release Date: 1962
 Genre: Action & Adventure
 Part of Compilation: no
 Part of Gapless Album: no
 Cover Art pieces: 1
 Copyright: © 1962 renewed 1990 Columbia Pictures Industries, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 Content Rating: None
 HD Video: yes
 Media Type: Movie
 Short Description: This monumental story recounts the true-life experiences of T.E Lawrence, better known to the world as Lawrence of Arabia. 
 Long Description: One of the screen's grandest epics, this monumental story recounts the true-life experiences of T.E. Lawrence, better known to the world as Lawrence of Arabia. A young, idealistic British officer in WWI, Lawrence (Peter O'Toole) is assigned to the camp of Prince Feisal (Alec Guinness), an Arab tribal chieftain and leader in a revolt against the Turks. In a series of brilliant tactical maneuvers, Lawrence leads fifty of Feisal's men in a tortured three-week crossing of the Nefud Desert to attack the strategic Turkish-held port of Aqaba. And following his successful raids against Turkish troops and trains, Lawrence's triumphant leadership and unyielding courage gain him nearly god-like status among his Arab brothers.
 Podcast: no
 Content ID: 533825997
 Artist ID: 56514470
 Playlist ID: 0
 Genre ID: 0
 iTunes Account: (redacted)
 iTunes Account Type: iTunes
 Purchase Date: 2014-05-06 13:48:29
 iTunes Store Country: United States
```

Comment: The AppleScript Dictionary for the TV app doesn't really offer any way to get to that information. Although the terminology has been updated for movies, it really is tailored to music. And the MP4Tools and ffmpeg deal with the technical aspects of the track; I don't need to modify the tracks themselves, I just want the information shown in "Info": title, director, actors, producer, screenwriters, studio,genre,year, and run time. Not interested in the rating or play count. I'm pretty sure that info is in the Library.tvdb file, but I can't find the format for that file.

Comment: Both of those tools show very detailed output, for me, with one iTunes-purchased video.  If you've added your own videos to the TV app, you'd be responsible for adding those tags yourself.  I'll update my answer with the output from those tools, as I can't add special formatting here in a comment.

Comment: I’ll give ffprobe a shot. Looks like it might do the trick. Thanks!